# iOS - Swift - Barcode scanner - Scanning area comes below the centre of the screen

Tags: swift, ipad, barcode, barcode-scanner, landscape

Not able to scan the barcode while the barcode is right in the centre of the screen, instead I have to capture the barcode  from a little below of the centre of the screen.

When I try to capture the bar code in the landscape mode, I have to scan the bar code below the centre of the screen. I want to scan the barcode only from the middle of the screen irrespective of the orientation of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

This code below has to be called in the main thread once you start capturing in different orientations. This code will help the focus area to be on the centre of the screen.

```
private var output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput?
private func configurePointOfInterests() {
    guard let device = self.captureDevice else { return }
    guard let videoPreviewLayer = self.videoPreviewLayer else { return }
    
    do {
        try device.lockForConfiguration()
        let point = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY)
        let convPoint = videoPreviewLayer.captureDevicePointConverted(fromLayerPoint: point)
        
        device.exposurePointOfInterest = convPoint
        device.focusPointOfInterest = convPoint
        device.unlockForConfiguration()
    } catch {
        delegate?.cameraViewController(self, didReceiveError: error)
    }
}

private func configureRectOfInterest() {
    if let roi = videoPreviewLayer?.metadataOutputRectConverted(fromLayerRect: self.view.bounds) {
        output?.rectOfInterest = roi
    }
}
```

Call in the main thread as below when you start capturing
self.captureSession.startRunning()

```
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.configurePointOfInterests()
                self.configureRectOfInterest()
            }
```